# Windows 7 installation on 16 GB USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, portable

I have a 16 GB USB and i want to install Windows 7(32 bit) on it.
Is 16 GB space enough to run and install windows 7(32 bit) flawlessly ?
On some websites people are saying all version of windows can be installed on 8 GB of USB,s.
Confused fella here

Comment: They may be referring to a USB Installation drive.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are using the 16GB USB drive to install Windows, or if you are trying to install Windows ON the 16GB USB drive. This is an important distinction, and the answer depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Windows 7 Ultimate on a 16 GB partition (on an internel drive) and it worked.  So I guess that size is not a problem.

BTW, during the installation process Windows will tell you about the recommended size or refuse to install if there is not enough disk space available.  So just give it a try :-)

Once installed you can remove some files or directories you do not need:

I removed all language related stuff or the languages i will not use.
You can reduce the size of the page file or move it to another place.